# Why was fdatasync() equivalent to fsync() in Linux 2.2 and earlier versions?

Tags: linux, manpage

As mentioned in the man page of fdatasync()

```
   In Linux 2.2 and earlier, fdatasync() is equivalent to fsync(), and
   so has no performance advantage.
```

I want to know why they were same in version 2.2 and before. Moreover, what changes were made in Linux, that today fdatasync() and fsync() are no longer equivalent.

Comment: Is it so hard to figure it out based on the manpage's description of what the difference between the two functions is?

Comment: @PSkocik I know what the difference is right now. But why was there no difference in Linux 2.2 and before? what changes were made in Linux?

Comment: One would assume they had fsync but not fdatasync so to provide fdatasync without doing any work, they plugged fsync into fdatasync, because it provides the same guarantee and more.

Comment: The flushing of the Inode  effectively doubles the amount of work for the disk.(and is often unneeded). So fdatasync was introduced.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/ is a better forum for this question.  StackOverflow is meant for programming questions while  UNIX & Linux StackExchange covers general questions.